# yay -Syu hangs on pipewire cloning

Tags: arch-linux, pipewire

When I run `yay -Syu` the terminal eventually hangs at this part.

```
==> Making package: pipewire-git 0.3.40.126.g1e5f499ed-1 (Mon 27 Dec 2021 02:14:22 PM EST)
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Cloning pipewire git repo...
Cloning into bare repository '/home/mycomputer/.cache/yay/pipewire-git/pipewire'...
```

Running `yay -R pipewire-git` gets me the followin output:

```
error: target not found: pipewire-git
 -> exit status 1
```

Comment: Do you have the /home/mycomputer directory?

Comment: I own it, yes..

Comment: I'm also not able to clone pipewire repository from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire but I know it used to work before.

Comment: May be related https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/freedesktop/freedesktop/-/issues/407

Answer (score 0):

gitlab.freedesktop.org is having some problems, you can read latest
admins announcements at
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/freedesktop/freedesktop/-/issues/407.

If `yay` uses git binary to clone repository you can work around this
problem by cloning a mirror from Github:

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/PipeWire/pipewire.insteadOf https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire.git
```

Now run your `yay` command again.

Comment: I actually ran `yay -Syu` and stopped encountering the problem in my question. I do not know why.

Comment: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/freedesktop/freedesktop/-/issues/407#note_1215113 _Seems to work from time to time ..._. You can use my advice in case problem occurs again in the future.